# How can i make to work more than one thread at the same time?

Tags: c, multithreading, multiprocessing

My problem is that with one thread everything works well, but if I use more than one thread the program doesn't work as it should. 
If I use more than one thread, I have to use one mutex or an array of mutex? I have tried to use a mutex array but it doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_SEATS 10 //0 free seat //1 seat not free 
//pthread_mutex_t mu[NUM_SEATS]; 
pthread_mutex_t mu=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; 
int v_seat[NUM_SEATS]={0}; int count=0;

int terminal_screen(int v[]);

void *booking(void *arg){

long int *ip,i;
    ip=(long int*)arg;
    i=*ip;

//printf("%d",i);  

int n;
pthread_mutex_lock(&mu);
printf("I'm thread # %ld\n",i);

    printf("Choose the seat that you want\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);

        if(v_seat[n-1]==0){
           v_seat[n-1]=1;
            printf("Seat available.Booking done by thread %ld\n",i);
         terminal_screen(v_seat);
            count++;
        }
        else{
        printf("Seat not available\nRiprova\n\n");

        }
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&mu);
pthread_exit(NULL); }


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int rc,i;   
    /*pthread_t tid,tid2;
    long int a=1;
    long int b=2;*/

     pthread_t tid[NUM_SEATS];
    pthread_t ta[NUM_SEATS];  

/*    for(i=0;i<NUM_SEATS;i++){
    pthread_mutex_init(&mu[i],NULL);
    }*/

    terminal_screen(v_seat);
    while(count!=NUM_SEATS){
    /*pthread_create(&tid,NULL,booking,(void*)&a);   
    pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,booking,(void*)&b);

    pthread_join(tid,NULL);
    pthread_join(tid2,NULL);*/

    for(i=0;i<NUM_SEATS;i++){    
    ta[i]=i;
        if(rc=pthread_create(&tid[i],NULL,booking,(void*)&ta[i])){
        printf("Error\n");
        }    
    }

    for(i=0;i<NUM_SEATS;i++){
    pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
    }
    };
    printf("\n\nAll seats are occupied..\n");  
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

int terminal_screen(int v[]){

int i;

    printf("These are the free seats\n");
    for(i=0;i<NUM_SEATS;i++){
    if(v[i]==0)    
    printf("\tSeat %d\n",i+1);
    }
}
```

This is my multithread problem.

***A   central computer    connected   to  remote  terminals   via communication   links   is  used    to  automate    seat reservations   for a   concert hall.   A   booking clerk   can display the current state   of  reservations    on  the 
    terminal    screen. To  book    a   seat,   a   client  chooses a   free    seat    and the clerk   enters  the number  of  the chosen  seat    at  the terminal    and issues  a   ticket. A   system  is  required    which   avoids  double-booking  of  the same    seat    while   allowing    clients free    choice  of  the available   seats.

    You have    to  design  and implement   with    threads or  processes   in  a   C   language    program a   model   of  the 
    system  in  order   that    your    model   does    not permit  double-bookings.

    Your    TERMINAL    process should  allow   the customer    to  choose  a   seat,   at  which   point   the process 
    should  query   to  determine   if  the seat    is  reserved    or  not.    If  the seat    is  not reserved,   then    it  should  be    booked    otherwise   nothing changes.***

Comment: How does your question not work? What are you expecting to happen and how does what you've written differ from that?

Comment: *doesn't work* means nothing. Please say what happens exactly.

Comment: Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

Answer (score 2):

There are four warnings that you should fix (activate warnings for your compiler).

Aside from that, the program works.

Whether you want a single mutex for all seats or a mutex per seat depends on the scenario (the theater seats is only one such scenario). If you decide per-seat mutexes, then you would lock and unlock mutexes *inside* the loop that checks the seat.

Also note the number of threads you are spawning: it is unusual to spawn one thread per seat (even if we consider other scenarios than seats). The number of threads might for example be chosen as the number of CPU cores the target computer has.

And the thread that wrote the "I'm thread #n" is not necessarily the thread who's `scanf` is the one that will receive the user's input: The scheduler can switch threads between the `printf` and `scanf`. That could be fixed by having a mutex around the printf-scanf combination too.

Reading from the console is not a realistic test for whether threading/locking is correct. A more realistic test would be to run threads that reserve/release seats millions of times per second (for testing purpose with a random number to choose the seat to reserve).